# Ensure class balanced batches while hyperparameter tuning keras models with grid search

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, class-imbalance, hyperparameter-tuning

Ensuring class balanced batches while training keras models is possible using [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) method. I used [imblearn.keras.BalancedBatchGenerator](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.keras.BalancedBatchGenerator.html) for that and it works fine!

But i wanted to do that with [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to fine-tune my model, so i created an inherited class KerasBatchClassifier([KerasClassifier](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/)) as a Keras Wrapper for the Scikit-Learn API. (Inspired by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40854232/9214357))

Ensuring class balanced batches to fit the model is working, but i haven't figured out how to do it with validation data ! Any ideas to do that ?